# Simple Javascript dropdown box enabling problem

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Suspect I am doing something stupid, but I can't see for the wood for the trees just now. Another pair of eyes will probably fix this instantly.

```
    <script>
        function ChkStatus1() {
            if (document.frm1.LabelReq_1.value = "1") {
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1[0].selected = true;
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1.disabled = true;
            }
            if(document.frm1.LabelReq_1.value = "0") {
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1.disabled = false;
            }
        }
</script>

                    <Select name="LabelReq_1" onchange="ChkStatus1();">
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                        <option value="0">No</option>
                    </Select>
                    <Select name="LabelReason_1" disabled="disabled">
                        <option>[Please select why not required]</option>
                        <option>Reason 1</option>
                        <option>Reason 2</option>
                        <option>Reason 3</option>
                        <option>Reason 4</option>
                        <option>Reason 5</option>
                    </Select>
```

When I select the No, everything works as I would expect, but then when I choose 'Yes' it performs the 'LabelReason_1[0].selected = true;' but then doesn't change the LabelReq_1 combo box.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Graeme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the = in your if statements to ==
= assigns the value, == denotes equality

```
<script>
        function ChkStatus1() {
            if (document.frm1.LabelReq_1.value == "1") {
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1[0].selected = true;
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1.disabled = true;
            }
            if(document.frm1.LabelReq_1.value == "0") {
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1.disabled = false;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Duh! Of course. This is what happens when you stare and stare at a problem - you miss the obvious. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use == or === instead of =:

```
<script>
        function ChkStatus1() {
            if (document.frm1.LabelReq_1.value == "1") {
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1[0].selected = true;
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1.disabled = true;
            }
            if(document.frm1.LabelReq_1.value == "0") {
                document.frm1.LabelReason_1.disabled = false;
            }
        }
</script>
```